# How to change UI of EntityEditorWithPicker?

Tags: user-controls, custom-control

I have created a custom EntityEditorWithPicker control. And now I need add TreeView control at the left hand of the PickerDialog, when it is shown. But I can't found how to get an instance of PickerDialog to add it on my control with TreeView. Where is located the instance of created PickerDialog? I need do something like this:

[image: url: http ://s210.codeinspot.com/q/1453441]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a class inherting PickerDialog, and SImpleQueryControl. In your class inherting PeopleEditor, override OnInit and set the PickerDialogType

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) 
{ 
   base.OnInit(e); 
   this.PickerDialogType = typeof(CustomPickerDialog); 

}
```

The class inheriting the SimpleQueryControl is where you can add the controls to the results table.

Check this [page](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2009/10/create-a-custom-picker-in-sharepoint-2010/) on how to overide PickerDialog. Also check this [page](http://igorinnet.blogspot.com/2007/10/customizing-entityeditorwithpicker.html) on how to inherit SimpleQueryControl

Comment: I have already read them. There are nothing about how to add my class inherited from PickerDialog to my own webcontrol, that was created earlier. Then show my own webcontrol, that contains class inherited from PickerDialog as a child when PickerDialog is shown.